# TextInput not realizing is empty until 2 'backspace' is pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a login form with 2 inputs, basic username/password. I'd like to validate both text values to disable or enable the "Login" button.

For some reason, my TextInput isn't detecting when it's really empty on the first try, unless I press backspace again and then my button will be disabled/enabled. There has to be related on the way I'm saving the states.

This is the code:

I got my states here as follows:

```
this.state = {
    loading: false,
    username: {
        text: '',
        valid: false
    },
    password: {
        text: '',
        valid: false
    },
    isLoginValid: false
};
```

Then the buttons are these:

```
 <TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={ (text) => { this.validateInput(text, 'username')}}
    onKeyPress={ this.checkValidation.bind(this) }
    value={this.state.username.text}
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    placeholder={'Username'}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 />

<TextInput
    secureTextEntry={true}
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={ (text) => { this.validateInput(text, 'password')}}
    onKeyPress={ this.checkValidation.bind(this) }
    value={this.state.password.text}
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    placeholder={'Password'}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
/>
```

And finally, these are the 2 functions where I handle the state for the button, don't worry about the boolean to enable/disable the button, that works fine.

```
validateInput(text, fieldname) {
    var stateObject = {
        text: text,
        valid: text.length > 0
    }
    this.setState({ [fieldname]: stateObject });
}

checkValidation() {
    var isValid = this.state.username.valid && this.state.password.valid;
    this.setState({isLoginValid: isValid});
}
```

Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using onChangeText instead of onKeyPress.
onChangeText passes the changed text as an argument for the callback, onKeyPress returns an object with the key pressed, so the warning is because the property text of password and username in state holds an object instead of string.

**EDIT**
About the second problem (with the backspaces), note that onKeyPress is called before onChange callbacks, so the validation is happening before you set the changed text, Try removing onKeyPress at all, and make the validation check inside validateInput before you setState. So you will call setState once with the final properties you want to set.

Comment: Yes, i was so stupid. I had to combine onChangeText with onKeyPress. Use checkValidation on the onKeyPress and the onChangeText would save the state. I feel so dumb.

Comment: I fixed it but do you know why it could be that if i delete the last character, seems that the state hasn't reflected that is empty, prolly it still has the last character on it as a value, unless i press backspace key again and then it grabs it.

Comment: Try removing onKeyPress at all, and make the validation check inside validateInput before you setState. So you will call setState once with the final properties you want to set.

Comment: Yes, u're right. Also, there might be a problem with the setState and a synchronization thing, after debugging i saw that after doing the setState, my password.value was still empty. I remember there was like a promise thing with setState that you could chain them, remember how it is? i don't play with react-native since 2016

Comment: Edited explenatio about the ba kspace thing in the answer.. about the promise thing, I'm not sure I understood the chaining thing. Plus, when exactly you see the value empty?

Comment: Whenever you do a setState and after that, you call a function that might use the recently changed states through setState, you might not see the change reflected right away. So setState has a callback, so you can do whatever after the state was changed for good.
`this.setState({ variable: newValue}, () => function() { // do after setState })`

Back when i used react-native, i remember i had the same issue hahaha. Thanks for replying and helping :)